# Wordpress disable /wp-admin registration form

Tags: php, wordpress, registration, captcha

I'm working on a site with a plugin that allows users to register in the sidebar with a CAPTCHA. However if you go to /wp-admin you can still register without a CAPTCHA, is there any way to disable the registration form when someone visits /wp-admin without disabling registration for the whole site so the sidebar registration widget still works?

To be clear I want to remove the form from /wp-admin not just disable registration for the site.

Comment: can you tell you code or you modifying a plugin ?

Comment: I'm using this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/sexy-login/ to do the login/register widget. I'm writing a plugin to do most of the other functions on the site, but this plugin works so there is no need to write my own. Ideally I'd add some code to my plugin rather than editing this one.

Answer (score -1):

Setup apache to restrict /wp-admin access using a .htaccess file.

Basic example,

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted access"
AuthUserFile ~/public_html/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was hoping to find a way to do it with in a plugin though.